# Does anyone currently have phpMyAdmin working on Google Apps Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, phpmyadmin

It used to work for me following this [tutorial](https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/05/26/setting-up-phpmyadmin-on-app-engine/). Stopped working for a couple days, worked again, and now completely stopped working. I desperately need a program to help me manage my CloudSQL database and have tried multiple times following multiple tutorials and multiple setups with phpMyAdmin with no luck. I then tried phpMiniAdmin, SQL Buddy, and Adminer. I also tried [this tutorial](http://novelcode.blogspot.com/2013/07/phpmyadmin-on-google-app-engine-part-2_16.html) with no luck. To be clear, I am able to access the database using the following code in my own php scripts,

```
new mysqli('localhost','<username>','<password>','<db>',0,'/cloudsql/<app-id>:db');
```

It seems like the main problem is something to do with "socket" vs "host" in the Google App Engine setup. My "app.yaml" matches the tutorial, excluding references to my app, and my "config.inc.php" is the following,

```
<?php
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '<#>';
$i = 0;
$host = '/cloudsql/<app-id>:db';
$type = 'socket';
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = $host;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = $type;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['McryptDisableWarning'] = true;
$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = true;
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 60;
$cfg['CheckConfigurationPermissions'] = false;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
?>
```

I'm currently using 4.0.10, but tried 4.1.7 with the same results. I am greeted by a blank screen,there is source code but screen is blank. In the Apps Engine error logs I don't have any errors, just warnings referencing the inability to find images,

```
Static file referenced by handler not found: phpMyAdmin/pma_logo.png
```

I would love to know if anyone is currently using phpMyAdmin or any other php software to access CloudSQL, if so, maybe they might have a tip or two as to what is going on. I'm willing to share anything relevant as well, just let me know what and I'll post it.

**EDIT: Got it working.** I'm not sure why it initially stopped worked, started working, and then stopped working again. During my trails and error trying to get it to work I started using different tools including Codenvy as opposed to the Google Apps Engine client for Windows. I went back to using the GAE Windows client and was finally successful in accessing phpMyAdmin in CloudSQL. I don't know for sure, but I suppose it's possible the reason I struggled with strange errors during some of my testing could have been related to using Codenvy as opposed to Google's own tools. I'm not saing Codenvy was the problem, just that if a person is having phpMyAdmin/CloudSQL issues, they might consider trying the GAE client before pulling all their hair out.

Comment: So what is the symptom of "stopped working"?

Comment: It worked without issue. I was greeted by the login screen, I would login, and then use the program. Last week I logged in and was greeted by a blank screen. A day and a half later I logged in and everything was normal. The next morning I logged in and I was again greeted by a blank screen. Currently, I no longer get the login screen, I am greeted by a blank screen with the source code showing what seems to be script generated by phpMyAdmin. The favicon also loads, so I know it's referencing the directory, it's just that the screen is blank. I've tried multiple browsers, same situation.

Comment: Here is the [page source code](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SdLo9.png) that loads.

Comment: There is a style thats says html: display: none;. Probably js is broken used to disable that, although I am not familiar with phpmyadmin souce

Comment: I opened it in IE and unchecked "display: none;" and it shows the following [image](http://i.imgur.com/iLzVI9I.jpg). I'm searching for anything related to why this is happening. I don't know if it's the problem, but thank you for giving me something to new to look for.

Comment: The problem is that probably it requires these files. Can you access them? Are they present. Look towards there.

Comment: There is a file "pma_logo.png" that I can't access, but it seems to be a generated file. Google results in nothing. I have another error that seems to be one of a kind as well, "Uncaught ReferenceError:PMA commonParams is not defined". Here's an [image](http://i.imgur.com/MbDLYww.png). I wish I had time to deconstruct phpMyAdmin, but I really just need it to work again. Right now I would really like to hear that at least one other person out there in the world has phpMyAdmin (or some other program) working with CloudSQL.

Comment: Something then i definately wrong with your setup. I would recommend installing phpMyadmin again since we cannot really define what the problem is. Also consider addressing this to the phpMyadmin guys if problem persists.

Comment: I'm not sure of the etiquette on this website, but I edited my original question to say that it started working again the other night. I received an email from Google yesterday morning talking about how CloudSQL is now "ready for everyone". I'm starting to wonder if they weren't simply doing some backend maintenance and that's all it was.

Comment: @user33443 - I had it working, but now since I cleared my browser data, the login credentials are gone. My MySQL login credentials when I use root from the terminal aren't working. I remember something finicky the last time I did this... any ideas? Is your phpmyadmin using 'root' for the user?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seemed to resolve itself. It's possible Google was doing some maintenance, I have no other explanation.

Comment: And, once again, without changing a single thing, it has stopped working again. Greeted with phpMyAdmin login screen, login, and straight to a blank page. Unbelievable. Still don't understand how I'm the only person out there that is having this problem.

Comment: You aren't the only person, I installed a fresh copy of phpmyadmin today and was greeted with the exact same blank white screen.